# SPARQL FILTER() using Jena not working properly

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

i'm running Ontology project on Netbeans using **Jena for SPARQL** (version 2.6.2 ) Queries, and now i'm trying to FILTERS for **Temperature** , this code doesn't work as expected and return no result

```
PREFIX ns: <http://www.semanticweb.org/pavilion/ontologies/2017/5/untitled-ontology-66#>

SELECT ?StarName ?Temperature
WHERE {
    ?star a ns:Star ;
    ns:possessesSpectralType ?SpectralType ;
    ns:possessesStarName ?StarName ;
    ns:possessesTemperature ?Temperature .
    FILTER (?Temperature > 10 ).
}
```

on the other hand i've tried this code and it works but only with Equal operator

```
PREFIX ns: <http://www.semanticweb.org/pavilion/ontologies/2017/5/untitled-ontology-66#>

SELECT ?star
WHERE {
    ?star a ns:Star ;
    ns:possessesSpectralType ?SpectralType ;
    ns:possessesStarName ?StarName ;
    ns:possessesTemperature ?Temperature .
    FILTER (?Temperature = ns:168 )
}
```

Comment: As I told you in your previous question, you have to distinguish between URIs and literals. Why is the value of the temperature a URI and not just a numeric literal? Please change this in your data and use `xsd:integer` or `xsd:decimal` as datatype, then the filter will work if you also use the correct datatype for the value used. In your current filter you use `10` which is just a shortcut for `"10"^^xsd:integer. If you use `xsd:decimal` in your data, then use `10.0` in the filter

Comment: by the way, is there any good reason for using an ancient version of Jena? I mean, the latest version is `3.12.0` and you're using a version from 2011, so it's more or less 8 years old ...

Comment: well, I mean you don't have to migrate to latest Jena, but in general it's recommended for sure. But to solve your original problem, you have to change your data modeling. `ns:possessesTemperature` should be a *data property* and the values are just numeric literals. You can change this in Protege or wherever you generate the data